# Buying a Tax Sale property

Tags: taxes, canada, ontario, foreclosure

If I buy an automobile or land in a tax sale (or tax deed sale) and the previous owner had financed or mortgaged the item, who is responsible to the lender for completing the payments/transaction?  I read in one question that the buyer would have to foreclose the house -- how would it apply in this case?